# Building and installing software on Max OSX (pgAgent)

Tags: macos, installation

Could someone help me get started with this?

I’m a bit of a newbie when it comes to building software from scratch.

What I’m trying to do is install pgAgent on a Mac OsX?

This [README](https://github.com/postgres/pgagent) could be explaining it, but running ‘make’ don’t seem to work?

Could someone help by providing more detailed step-by-step instructions; would be much appreciated.

Software located here: https://github.com/postgres/pgagent

Comment: What happens if you run `make`?

Comment: I can’t find the makefile, it just says command not found.

Comment: Well, have you installed `cmake` on your Mac?

Comment: No, how could I get and install this for OSX?

Comment: Also, according to the README, do I still run ccmake, i.e. steps 3,4,5, or just step 6?

Answer (score 0):

Install the dependencies (`cmake` at least) using [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew), [Macports](http://www.macports.org/), or [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/). Then try compiling it again.

---

You will also need to install a C compiler. It is provided e.g. with Apple's developer tools.

---

If you don't need to compile it yourself, a [binary is provided](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin3/release/pgagent/) for OS X (Darwin). Just move the included binary to `/usr/bin/pgagent` and the `.sql` file to `/usr/share/pgagent.sql` .

Comment: Also, could you explain this step: "- A wxWidgets 2.8.x installation, configured per the requirements for
  pgAdmin:
  http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pgadmin3.git;a=blob_plain;f=INSTALL;hb=HEAD"

Comment: Ok thanks, but the more detailed instructions are for installing pgAdmin (which I already have), so I’m not sure what I’m missing for installing pgAgent (which is something different).

Comment: Also, on the download page, am I using Source, or Darwin. (http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin3/release/pgagent/)

Comment: @Larry Ah well I should have tried reading then :-) You can download `darwin`, that's the compiled program. It works on OS X, at least to display the usage instructions when started without arguments.

Comment: Cool, so I don’t have to compile? So is it a binary? Where do I place it in the system? thanx.

Comment: @Larry It includes both `bin` and `share`. `/usr` seems like a sensible destination, i.e. `/usr/bin/pgagent` and `/usr/share/pgagent.sql`. It's on your `PATH` by default then, so you can run it by typing `pgagent`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. Seems I’m reading to go then... I’m not sure why it doesn’t just say that in the installation instructions then.

Comment: I'm looking for the binaries for OSX, the link above now only contain the source code and I'm not experience compiling c code. I'm already do an extensive Google search by no lucky. I'll appreciate some help, hint or link. Thanks.

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this in 2016?